# VueJS Component Not Rendering Data

Tags: vue.js

I am just starting with Vue and single file components.  I am attempting to render two components.  One is a table displaying a list of asteroid data.  The other contains two images from NASA's astronomy picture of the day API.

I am successfully rendering my AsteroidGrid component, I am receiving data from the endpoint and it is working fine,- rows are able to be deleted.

But my second component doesn't seem to be working.  It is making a call to two NASA endpoints and successfully receiving the response data.  But for some reason the data (imgSrc and imgTitle) isn't populating my component.

https://vue-mazzo.herokuapp.com/#

Here is my App.vue file

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

 <Apod>
    <h3 slot="title">#1</h3>
    <p slot="caption">Here' today's Astronomy Picture of the Day</p>
  </Apod>

  <Apod date="2018-08-07">
    <h3 slot="title">#2</h3>
    <p slot="caption" slot-scope="pic">Here's the picture from {{pic.date}} 
   </p>
  </Apod>

  <AsteroidGrid @remove="remove" :asteroids="asteroids" header="Near-Earth 
Objects"/>

  </div>
</template>
    <script>
    import AsteroidGrid from './components/AsteroidGrid.vue'
    import Apod from './components/Apod.vue'
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {
          AsteroidGrid,
          Apod

    },
    data() {
      return{
        asteroids: [],
        showSummary:true,
        imgSrc: '',
        imgTitle: ''
        }

    },
    created: function(){
        this.fetchAsteroids();
        this.fetchApod();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchAsteroids:function(){
            var apiKey = 'WjNITMO5uO6l4E0HeLKxmwdmF25SdRn4KXcsxDbY';
            var url = 'https://cors- 
        anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://737798.youcanlearnit.net/neos.json';
        axios.get(url)
            .then(res => {
                console.clear();
                console.log(res);
                this.asteroids = res.data.near_earth_objects.slice(0,10);
                //vm.asteroids = res.data.near_earth_objects.slice(0,10);
            });
    },

    remove:function(index){
        //this.$emit('remove', index);
        this.asteroids.splice(index,1);
        // this.asteroids = [];
    },
    fetchApod: function(){
              var apiKey = 'WjNITMO5uO6l4E0HeLKxmwdmF25SdRn4KXcsxDbY';
              var url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=' + apiKey;


              if(this.date){
                  url += '&date=' + this.date;
              }
             var self = this;
              axios.get(url)
                  .then(function (res) {
                      console.clear();
                      console.log(res);
                      self.imgSrc = res.data.url;
                      self.imgTitle = res.data.title;
                  });
          }   
    }//end methods
}//end export default
</script>

<style>
/* #app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
} */

 [v-cloak] {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Here is my Apod.vue file

```
<template>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
        <slot name="title"><h3>Untitled</h3></slot>
        <img width="300" height="200" :src="imgSrc" :title="imgTitle">
        <!--<p>{{date || "today"}}</p>-->
        <slot name="caption" :date="date"><p>unkown date</p></slot>
     </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    props: ['date'],
    data: function(){
        return {
        imgSrc: '',
        imgTitle: ''
        }
    },
    created: function(){

    this.fetchApod();
},

methods:{
        fetchApod: function(){
            var apiKey = 'WjNITMO5uO6l4E0HeLKxmwdmF25SdRn4KXcsxDbY';
            var url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=' + apiKey;


            if(this.date){
                url += '&date=' + this.date;
            }

            axios.get(url)
                .then(res => {
                    console.clear();
                    console.log(res);
                    this.imgSrc = res.data.url;
                    this.imgTitle = res.data.title;
                });
        }   
    } //End methods
 }//End export default
</script>
```

Comment: In **App.vue** `components:` uncomment `//Apod`. Also try to restart dev server

Comment: @ljubadr yeah I had done that, removing the comment from the Apod component registration.  Restarted the dev server too.  Still getting the build error.

Comment: You are also missing closing div for `<div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6">` in `Apod.vue`

Comment: @ljubadr: So I added the closing div.  I am getting past the build now and rendering.  But src data is not populating my component.  Check out a live demo here: https://vue-mazzo.herokuapp.com/#

Comment: Try `<img width="300" height="200" :src="imgSrc" :title="imgTitle" v-if="imgSrc">`. Note added `v-if="imgSrc"`. So it won't render the image until the url is not empty.

Comment: @ljubadr: unfortunately, that did not work either...

Comment: Add `import axios from 'axios'` to  `Apod`

Comment: @ljubadr: no dice...

Comment: Try not to use `console.clear();` as it will hide the errors from you. I've set the **preserve log** in devtools, and I see the `ReferenceError: axios is not defined` when I look at heroku link

Comment: Update the heroku example if you can

Comment: Also, you can always put keyword `debugger;` into your code, and if the devtools is open, it will stop at that point (same as putting the breakpoint) and you can inspect the data

Comment: @ljubadr: I'm stuck...

Comment: Update the heroku example, so I can look into it

Comment: @ljubadr the Heroku example is updated...

Comment: In the `Apod` you commented out the `created: function(){` method, so it will never fetch the data in that component

Comment: @ljubadr: but in App.vue the function is there and being called.

Comment: I just noticed that. You do call the `fetchApod`, but you never use the returned data in the `App.vue` and you don't pass that down as props to components. So you can remove `fetchApod` method, `imgSrc` and `imgTitle` from data in from `App.vue` and uncomment `created` method in your `Apod` component

Comment: @ljubadr I'm not sure I follow you.  I am using the response data in App.vue I'm setting the imgSrc and imgTitle properties with it: this.imgSrc = res.data.url; this.imgTitle = res.data.title;

Comment: In **App.vue** you do set the values, but you don't use those values in the **App.vue** template and you don't pass those values to other components. So it's same as not being used. Also, `imgSrc` and `imgTitle` from **App.vue** are **NOT THE SAME** as `imgSrc` and `imgTitle` in your **Apod** component.

Comment: You can safely remove `fetchApod` from **App.vue** and uncomment `created` method in **Apod.vue**

Comment: @ljubadr The values are being used in the App.vue template.  The Apod element, is using the template in Apod.vue.  There is where those returned values are being used.

Comment: @ljubadr: It is working now.  You can check the heroku example.  Many many thanks.  You should put an answer and I'll check it as the official answer.

Comment: Hey, I'm glad it worked! Looks great :) I don't have the time right now to post the answer, so you can go ahead and do it yourself, I won't mind. I'm glad I could help